# How can I configure the date format in strapi (version 4) for the admin panel?

Tags: strapi

In the admin panel of the cms Strapi (version 4!) the date is shown in a very long format:

[image: strapi admin panel]

Is it possible to change this to e.g. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format?

I have tried the way described [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12216) but that does not work in V4.
The issue does not seem to be solved yet. Is anybody out there with a good workaround?

Comment: It doesn't seems possible at the moment on V4. You can vote and subscribe here: https://feedback.strapi.io/developer-experience/p/option-to-change-the-date-format-in-the-admin-dashboard